# How do I implement a start-stop button / play-resume button for an animation in bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, widget, bokeh

I am trying to implement a star-stop button for a bokeh animation. I am using bokeh server in combination with the curdoc() function, but so far I haven't had much success.

I am wondering how someone with more experience would do that?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. Run with `bokeh serve --show app.py` (tested on Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Toggle, Column
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from datetime import datetime
import random

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(time = [datetime.now()], value = [random.randint(5, 10)]))
plot = figure(plot_width = 1200, x_axis_type = 'datetime', tools = 'pan,box_select,crosshair,reset,save,wheel_zoom')
plot.line(x = 'time', y = 'value', line_color = 'black', source = source)
toggle = Toggle(label = "Toggle", button_type = "success")

def update():
    if toggle.active:
        source.stream(dict(time = [datetime.now()], value = [random.randint(5, 10)]))

curdoc().add_root(Column(plot, toggle))
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 1000)
```

Result:

[image]